# NOTEBOOK_METADATA_FILE detected but failed to get valid domain and user from it

Tags: jupyter-notebook, metadata, amazon-sagemaker, training-data

I am new to Amazon sagemaker but I'm trying to train a ResNet50 model for semantic segmentation using a Jupiter Notebook. When calling the sagemaker estimator I have the error: "NOTEBOOK_METADATA_FILE detected but failed to get valid domain and user from it." or "WARNING: sagemaker.interactive_apps.base_interactive_app: NOTEBOOK_METADATA_FILE detected but failed to get valid domain and user from it.".

I tried to restart kernel of the notebook and to restart the notebook instance but the error persist.

[these are my Notebook Metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ8LC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can verify whether you have having all the permissions on the account from which you are running the notebook. You can check that on the IAM or ask your admin to verify the IAM for the account of your SageMaker for the required permissions for VPC access and other needed policies.